# Consolidating 2 Tables with same Values

Tags: sql-server, migration, duplication

I am working on a project trying to consolidate two databases, `DB1` and `DB2`, for my organization into a single database, `DB3`.

Initially our organization started with `DB1`.  A few years back they made a new database called `DB2` and moved on to using only `DB2`.

Currently, I am working on the `Orders` Table.

Since new rows were inserted into `DB2` without importing existing rows from `DB1`, `Order-id` Column values started from 1 instead of continuing from where the `Order-id` Column in `DB1` had ended.

I have many `Order-id` Column values that are the same in both Tables that represent different orders.

For example `Order-id = 100` in `DB1` refers to order "X", whereas `Order-id = 100` in `DB2` refers to order "Y".

If I insert rows from both `DB1.Orders` and `DB2.Orders` into `DB3.Orders` there will be duplicate rows representing different orders.

As I have not come across this sort of situation before, I need a suggested approach for  dealing with this.

Comment: Are those order id values just in this table, or do they have references in other tables too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, the lack of an `uint` type in SQL Server can come in handy. If `Order-id` is defined as `identity(1,1)` in `DB2`, you likely do not have any negative `Order-id`s.

Consider importing all the legacy `DB1..Orders.Order-id` fields as the same number, but multiplied by -1. If there's a FK to `Order-id` in `DB1`, you would use the same multiple-by-negative-one conversion when those records are loaded into their corresponding tables in `DB2`.

With this method, you also have the benefit of easily identifying the legacy orders originally from `DB1` because their `Order-id` is always negative (just be sure to document this.)

**Edit - added an example**

```
-- Assumptions:
-- DB1 and DB2 are on the same server
-- The table Orders is in the dbo schema
-- Order-id is an integer-type in DB1 and DB2
-- Order-id >= 0 in DB1 and DB2
-- Order-id is an identity(a, b), where a and b >=0 in DB2

-- Overview: Insert records from DB1 into DB2, but reverse the
-- sign of Order-id (i.e., positive to negative).

Use DB2
Go

Set Identity_Insert dbo.Orders On;

Insert dbo.Orders
(Order-id, col2, col3)

Select (-1 * Order-id), col2, col3
From DB1.dbo.Orders;

Set Identity_Insert dbo.Orders Off;
Go

-- Have related records? Insert them here.
```

Comment: If you have FK constraints with cascading updates, they will automatically apply the update to the referenced key.